# find out if file is a video or an image with ffmpeg

Tags: c, image, video, ffmpeg

is there any direct way of finding out whether file is an image or video while using ffmpeg library?

i know i can get codec_id from AVCodecContext (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html), but enumeration at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce

is really huge and doesnt seem to be categorized..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok after investigating ffprobe sources seems that i found something which helps (not sure if it's 100% reliable)

```
AVFormatContext->iformat->name
```

but similar problem there .. lot of uncategorized possibilities. except that it returns "image2"/"gif"/"ico" in case of an image. more image formats can appear, all supported are listed at http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Image-Formats

if it's not an image, it is necessarry to analyze all streams and detect video stream within them (to know it's a video not an audio or subtitles file). basically check for:

```
AVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
```

it is still necesarry to check iformat->name first, because streams check returns AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO both for images and videos.